# Pass in proper path for Servlet in .jsp

Tags: jsp

I have a .jsp file which has to submit the request to ResultServlet

but i am getting the error

HTTP Status 404 - /project1/jsp//ResultServlet

The problem is that my ResultServlet is in /project1/src/ResultServlet

Can you tell me what changes i need to make to the action field in .jsp so that it starts looking in folder
src instead of folder jsp

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you'd like to use a relative URL to the servlet in `<form action>` of the JSP. First you need to determine the **full** URL of both the JSP and the Servlet and then extract the relative URL to the Servlet from the JSP.

Let's assume that your JSP is on http://example.com/context/jsp/page.jsp and that your Servlet is on http://example.com/context/src/servlet. So to reach the Servlet from the JSP you have to go one level up `../` so that you lands in http://example.com/context and finally go from there to `src/servlet`.

```
<form action="../src/servlet">
```

Alternatively, you can also use the context path if you don't want to be dependent on the location/URL of the JSP:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/src/servlet">
```