# Wrong URL after clicking submit on JSP from

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and I am dealing with a confusing issue. I have a JSP form located in a sub folder called "admin" in my web-app (named "CMS").

```
CMS/admin/display_content.jsp
```

My form has the following values for action and method attribute

```
<form action="/deleteContent" method="POST">
```

/deleteContent is the URL pattern for a servlet named DeleteContentServlet. It simply deletes from the DB the user selections. Anyway, my problem is once I click on submit I notice that I get the incorrect URL in my address bar. Instead of getting

```
http://localhost:8080/CMS/deleteContent
```

I get

```
http://localhost:8080/deleteContent
```

How can I fix this ? When I have sub folders, are the files only used for imports maybe ?
Thank you.

Comment: Consider using `<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path">`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919998/pass-in-proper-path-for-servlet-in-jsp

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you. I should have mentioned I am using JSTL but this helped me understand how urls are interpreted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the JSTL `<c:url>` tag for all your URLs:

- it prepends the context path (whatever it is) to absolute URLs
- it writes the session ID in the URL in case the browser doesn't accept cookies:

  ```
  <form action="<c:url value='/deleteContent'/>" method="POST">
  ```

For links, it also allows passing parameters to the URL, and encodes them properly (via the `<c:param>` inner tag).

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?577109-Get-Servlet-Context-from-JSP), you can use request.getContextPath() in your servlet to get the context path. And you need not specify the hostname for the action unless it is different than yours:

```
<form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/deleteContent" method="POST">
```

Hope that helps...